# Gradient of 3d delta-function

Tags: vector-analysis, dirac-delta

I need to evaluate the following expression:

$\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha}\delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\right]v(\boldsymbol{r})$

and I want to make use of the fact, that the gradient can be transferred to the function v, I know that in the 1d case

$\int dx \frac{d\delta(x-a)}{dx}f(x) = -\int dx \delta(x-a)\frac{f(x)}{dx}$

But somehow it does not help me a lot in solving the above expression. I guess the solution is not difficult, but I want to be 100% sure about the sign also, since the delta-function has the $\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha$ with a negative sign ahead, or does that not matter and the solution is just

$\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha}\delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\right]v(\boldsymbol{r}) = -\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha}v(\boldsymbol{r})\right]$???

Please help me in my confusion...

(v depends also on $\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha$ via $v(\boldsymbol{r}) = \sum_\beta v(|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\beta|$)

---

So far the comments suggest:

\begin{align}
\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha}\delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\right]v(\boldsymbol{r}) &= -\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}\delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\right]v(\boldsymbol{r}) \\&= \int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\left[\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}v(\boldsymbol{r})\right]= \int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\left[\sum_\beta \nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}} v_\beta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\beta)\right]\\
&=-\int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r} \delta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha)\left[\sum_\beta \nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\beta} v_\beta(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_\beta)\right] = -\sum_\beta \nabla_{\boldsymbol{R}_\beta} v_\beta(\boldsymbol{R}_\alpha-\boldsymbol{R}_\beta)
\end{align}

Is that correct?

Comment: Is $v$ scalar valued or vector valued? If it is vector-valued, is there a dot product in between? Also, I'm not sure you will be able to just move the delta function over to $v$ because you are differentiating with respect to a different variable than the integration variable. Thus integration by parts does not hold in the usual way.

Comment: Good idea, that could be true. v is scalar valued and can be expanded into components centered at $R_\beta$. Would it be maybe possible to change then the gradient to a gradient concerning $\boldsymbol{r}$? Since the delta-function is symmetric to the vector difference that should be ok right? In that case it would be possible to transfer it?

Comment: Yes, you will want to rewrite $\nabla_{R_\alpha} \delta(r-R_{\alpha})$ in terms of $\nabla_r$ instead. (I do believe there is a chain rule minus sign, however.)

Comment: I have edited my question including your idea, would you be so nice to recheck, if everything is ok? Is there a sign missing?